# MVC Core Root Path Is Not Prefixed with wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have deployed an MVC Core 2.0 application and when I load any of my pages I can see that they javascript and css files are not pointing to the correct address.

For example, `/lib/bootstrap-table...` should be `/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-table...`.

The application works perfectly when debugging locally via Visual Studio, however.

I have the following configuration in my Startup.cs:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Yet, the file paths are still not prefixed with `/wwwroot`.  Why doesn't MVC find the correct file path?

[image]

The Layout.cshtml file has the following; however, if I prefix the files with `/wwwroot` then the files are no longer found when debugging:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.min.css" />
</environment>
```

I can see in my Program.cs file that ContentRoot is set to CurrentDirectory, but it works when debugging just not when deployed to a server.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: how your code looks like which is adding css and js files in master layout?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Thanks for your comment.  I updated the question.

Comment: No.`wwwroot` is the static content root by default. So you do not need to include that in the url.

Comment: Can @user1477388 show the `Program.cs` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` already sets up the default configurations, i.e., `UseKestrel()`, `UseContentRoot()` etc. You don't need to call them again.

Instead you only need this

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

And `app.UseStaticFiles()` makes the files in `wwwroot` folder (by default) servable. That is, a request like `http://<your_domain>/<your_app>/css/site.css` will try to get the `site.css` under the structure `wwwroot/css/`.

You don't need to manually append `wwwroot` in the static file urls.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; deleting those lines doesn't seem to effect the result in this case; however.  The files are still not pointing to the wwwroot directory upon deployment thus they are not found.

Comment: The URLs don't need to have the wwwroot as part of the URL. `UseStaticFiles()` extension should already make the `wwwroot` folder servable. All files inside that folder should be accessible. For example, if you have a `site.css` under `wwwroot/css/` structure, a request like `http://[YOUR_DOMAIN]/[YOUR_APP]/css/site.css` will serve the css file. The URL doesn't need to have `wwwroot` in it.

Comment: How/where is the redirect handled?  The files are physically located at `~/wwwroot/css...`, `~/wwwroot/js`, etc.

Comment: What do you mean? `wwwroot` folder is the root of your website (by default, of course, you can change it to whatever you like). That is, `http://your.domain/app` points to the wwwroot folder. All URLs for static content are relative to the wwwroot folder.

Comment: You were right.  The problem was not related to this; rather, it was due to the production transform pointing to minified files that actually weren't on the server.  Thanks for your help and explanation.